# What's right order to queue multiple opencl kernels in loop

Tags: loops, kernel, opencl

What is right algorithm to queue multiple opencl kernels in loop?
Code is following:

```
for(int i=0;i<numIter;i++){ // numIter = 1000
//
status = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commandQueue,kernel1,2,NULL,globalThreads,localThreads,0,NULL,NULL);
ASSERT_CL(status);
status = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commandQueue,kernel2,2,NULL,globalThreads,localThreads,0,NULL,&ndrEvt);
ASSERT_CL(status);
if(i>0 && i%16==0){ // 16 - just
status = clFlush(commandQueue);
ASSERT_CL(status);
spinForEventsComplete( 1, &ndrEvt );
//status = clWaitForEvents(1, &ndrEvt);
//ASSERT_CL(status);
}
}
status = clFlush(commandQueue);
ASSERT_CL(status);
spinForEventsComplete( 1, &ndrEvt );
```

Or should to use wait after every clEnqueueNDRangeKernel call?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong whit what you have done. Have you tried waiting after each NDRange? have you tried not waiting at all and queuing all NDRanges? Does either alternative work better for you?

Comment: Thanx, I'm trying different variants with/without waits, the problem is not stable results, both kernels exchange data in global memory, but sometimes wrong data in final buffer. Kernels are pretty simple just calculations, no local memory, no inner loops, no barriers.

Comment: the different kernel calls could be overwriting the previous results. when you wait for each NDRange one at a time, do you still have the final data issue?

Comment: yes, any variants with or without waits, no stable work. I'm using amd app sdk 3.0 betta

Answer (score 0):

It really depends a lot on how big your kernels are. If they take a long time to run, lots of waiting on the host probably doesn't matter. If they are small you may want to queue up a huge number of them to reduce the overhead per launch.

I would naturally write that loop without any waits until the very end, but maybe inserting the flush every few iterations as you have. How frequent you want to flush will be architecture dependent and a good tuning parameter to play with.

I'd also lean towards writing the code with all event dependencies, it's a good habit to be in even if your code can happily rely on an in-order queue.